# In SI units, use text font numerals or math font numerals?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, typography, units

I am using Palatino and Neo Euler. When typesetting SI units with `siunitx` package the font for the unit is changed to the text roman, but the numerals are still from the math alphabet. Euler has a distinctive numerals, so what do you think? Should the numerals match the typeface used for the unit? Or should they remain as Euler?

[image]

My thought:

When the unit is in line, surrounded by text it is, maybe, better to use the palatino numerals. But this leads to inconsistency with units given in equations or numerals in tables.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mykern.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;
feature kern {
  pos V  \slash -250;
} kern;

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[FeatureFile=mykern.fea]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{euler.otf}
%\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\showoutput
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Euler + Palatino & \SI[per-mode = symbol]{300}{\mega\volt\per\metre}\\
\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
Palatino + Palatino & \SI[per-mode = symbol]{300}{\mega\volt\per\metre}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Be consistent: either always Euler or never.

Comment: Yes of course. But what do you think about the inconsistency of using euler numeral with the palatino letters?

Comment: That's *your* choice, not mine. If you decide to use Euler for the digits, do it for all numbers (when they are used in their mathematical meaning, which doesn't include page, chapter or section numbers).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typographic question rather than how to _implement_ the desired outcome using TeX or a related system.

Comment: @egreg I agree that it's their choice, but you don't have to be that harsh

Comment: @Ooker Do you see harshness? I don't and of course I didn't mean to be harsh.

Comment: @egreg I didn't see harshness either. It is the problem of the written communication.